# Opencart - display one of two product's category

Tags: php, opencart

I have Opencart 1.5.1.3 and have modified Meta title to display "Product name - Product category"

> $product_info['name'] . ' - ' . $category_info['name']

The problem is when some of the products belong to two or more categories. How to tell open cart to use any one of product's categories? I don't really care which one :)

```
$this->language->load('product/product');

    $this->data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

    $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text'      => $this->language->get('text_home'),
        'href'      => $this->url->link('common/home'),         
        'separator' => false
    );

    $this->load->model('catalog/category'); 
    $this->request->get['path'] = (isset($this->request->get['path']))? $this->request->get['path'] : $this->model_catalog_category->getCategoryPath($this->request->get['product_id']);

    if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
        $path = '';

        foreach (explode('_', $this->request->get['path']) as $path_id) {
            if (!$path) {
                $path = $path_id;
            } else {
                $path .= '_' . $path_id;
            }

            $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($path_id);

            if ($category_info) {
                $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                    'text'      => $category_info['name'],
                    'href'      => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $path),
                    'separator' => $this->language->get('text_separator')
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That really depends on how you have selected the category info. Post your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have above assumes you get to a product via the categories, when in fact that doesn't always happen. Instead, you want to do the following

Find this line in `/catalog/controller/product/product.php`

```
$this->document->setTitle($product_info['name']);
```

Replace it with the following

```
        $result = $this->db->query("
            SELECT `cd`.`name`
            FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category` `p2c`
            LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "category_description` `cd`
            ON `cd`.`category_id` = `p2c`.`category_id`
            WHERE `p2c`.`product_id` = '" . (int) $product_id . "'
            AND `cd`.`language_id` = '" . $this->confing->get('config_language_id') . "'
            ORDER BY `cd`.`category_id` DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ");

        $category_name = $result->num_rows ?  $result->row['name']: '';
        $this->document->setTitle($product_info['name'] . (empty($category_name) ? '' : ' - ' . $category_name));
```

That will always show the last category created as the category assigned to the product. It will also not show a category if one isn't assigned to it (and hide the -)